# Multiple criteria for sumif in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to calculate the sum of column in google spreadsheet when
DataSheet!G:G="solved" AND DataSheet!C:C="May" it must calculate the sum of DataSheet!H:H.

I have tried

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(((DataSheet!C:C)="May") * ((DataSheet!G:G)="solved") * (DataSheet!H:H) ))
```

But it returns N/A can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula would only returns `N/A` if a value on your H column is `N/A`. Have you checked that? And, are you sure it's `N/A` and not other kind of error?

If so, can you please share your spreadsheet, or a sample of it so I can take a look for myself, because I can't reproduce this.

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(DataSheet!C:C&DataSheet!G:G;"Jan"&"solved";DataSheet!H:H))

Comment: This is not an answer. That's just an alternate formula. Your original one works fine for me.

Comment: The original 1 didnt work on mine not sure why, but the 2nd one does... so thanks again.