# How can I set multiple criterias for a Google Spreadsheet SumIF formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I want a formula which sums column `D` if column `K` has a value between 3000 and 4000. I've tried the following but none work:

```
=SUMIF(K3:K67; ">= 3000 & < 4000";D3:D67)
=SUMIF(K3:K67; ">= 3000 " & " < 4000";D3:D67)
=SUMIF(K3:K67; ">= 3000 AND < 4000";D3:D67)
```

Is this possible or must I use the ArrayFormula function (which I don't understand) like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635029/multiple-criteria-for-sumif-google-spreadsheet)?

**Edit:** This works, so there's nothing wrong with the data:

```
=SUMIF(K3:K67; ">= 3000";D3:D67)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit:** Google Sheets now supports [SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496).

**Original answer:**
There are a number of ways to do this. A little while ago I spent some time working out which method is the most watertight (for example, I am guessing the formula in the original post of the question you linked may have failed because there were probably text entries - perhaps a header - in the column to be summed).

IMO this is the most watertight general solution for a multi-conditional sum in Google Sheets:

`=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(sum_range;condition_1;condition_2;...)))`

so in your specific case:

`=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(D3:D67;K3:K67>=3000;K3:K67<4000)))`

*Although* the same can be achieved with the following:

`=SUMIF(K3:K67;"<4000";D3:D67)-SUMIF(K3:K67;"<3000";D3:D67)`

but I guess these "in-between" conditions are a special case where you can do this; the first solution is perhaps a better general solution.

Comment: There was no fault in the data in the original question - see edit. But I liked your last solution. Simple and effective!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. BTW I wasn't referring to a potential flaw in your data - I was referring to the question you linked to in your original post.

Comment: See @wikier's answer for a better way to do this in the current version of google docs.

Comment: Hmm. You could probably add an edit to the top of your answer pointing out that this has changed and to see the other answer (or just link to the sumifs function)?

Answer (score 11):

The answer of this question is **deprecated** since [SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en) is now included, adding support to multiple criterias to `SUMIF`.